# Conditional mutating of the R data frame based on the strings

Tags: r, dplyr

I am using R and trying to create a new column based on the string information from the existing columns.

My data is like:

> ```
> risk_code          |  area
> -----------------------------------
> DEEP DIGGING ALL   |  --
> CONSTRUCTION PRO   |  Construction
> CLAIMS ONSHORE     |  --
> OFFSHORE CLAIMS    |  --
> ```

And the result I need is:

> ```
> risk_code          |  area          |  area_new
> -------------------------------------------------
> DEEP DIGGING ALL   |  --            |  Digging
> CONSTRUCTION PRO   |  Construction  |  Construction
> CLAIMS ONSHORE     |  --            |  Onshore
> OFFSHORE CLAIMS    |  --            |  Offshore
> ```

I understanding that I make several mistakes in the code, but after the whole week of staring on it and internet searching, I cannot get the result I need.
I appreciate your help.
Thanks in advance.

```
Occupancy <- read_excel("Occupancy.xlsx")

OccupancyMutated <- mutate(Occupancy, area_new = area)
OccupancyMutated <- as.data.frame(OccupancyMutated)

OccupancyMutated$area_new[Occupancy$area == "--"] <- 
{ 
  if (OccupancyMutated$risk_code == %Digging%) {"Digging"}
else if (OccupancyMutated$risk_code == %ONSHORE%) {"Onshore"}
else if (OccupancyMutated$risk_code == %OFFSHORE%) {"Offshore"}
  else {"empty"}
}
View(OccupancyMutated)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `stringr` for this operation. The function `word` will extract the first word of each string in `risk_code` and the function `str_to_title` will convert to your required format. Both functions are vectorized so simply,

```
library(stringr)

str_to_title(word(df$risk_code, 1, 1))
#[1] "Digging"      "Construction" "Onshore"      "Offshore"
```

If it is not always the first word and you need to do it for specific words only, you can do,

```
str_to_title(str_extract(tolower(df$risk_code), 'digging|offshore|onshore'))
#[1] "Digging"  NA         "Onshore"  "Offshore"
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer.
Unfortunately, it is not always the first word.
I will change my example to make it more clear.

Comment: Edited. Have a look and let me know

Answer (score 1):

So, this is the answer (thanks to Sotos):

```
Occupancy <- read_excel("Occupancy.xlsx")

OccupancyMutated <- mutate(Occupancy, area_new = area)
OccupancyMutated <- as.data.frame(OccupancyMutated)

OccupancyMutated$area_new[Occupancy$area == "--"] <- 
str_to_title(str_extract(tolower(Occupancy$risk_code), 'Extraction|Offshore|Onshore'))

View(OccupancyMutated)
```

Comment: Since you are using `tolower`, make sure that the pattern you are looking for (in your case `Extraction|Offshore|Onshore`) are also written in lower letters